# The "suggested tags" and "similar questions" on ask question page doesn't disappear on clicking discard button

Tags: bug, asking-questions, similar-questions, suggested-tags

While posting a question by [Ask Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), after filling title and body, based on the content there is a "suggested tags" which suggesting few tags related to the post.

In case if I want to remove the post content, it can be done by clicking on the "Discard" button next to the "Post Your Question" button. On clicking on the Discard button the content in the **Title**, **Body** and **Tags** are removed but the **suggested tags** section doesn't disappear, it seems a bug to me.

GIF for the same:

> [image: Discarding the question]

**Update:**

In case if **Similar Questions** section is displayed in the side bar for the post and after the "Discard", for the body instead of **How to Format** section it is still displaying the **Similar Questions** section only.

GIF for the same:

> [image: After discard - similar questions]